# How can I log the negotiated SSL Cipher in Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl, iis-7, logging

I have a web server running IIS 7.0, on Windows Server 2008 R2. The web application is written in C# .Net 4.0. The web application receives web requests, and sometimes makes outbound https requests to other services.

I want to log the SSL cipher negotiated for each web request received by my web server.
I also want to log the SSL cipher negotiated for each web request initiated by my web server.

This question looks similar to mine, but doesn't have a good answer.

[SSL negotiation logging in IIS](https://serverfault.com/questions/65285/ssl-negotiation-logging-in-iis)

I've found these references here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb648705(v=vs.85).aspx

Am I warm? Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Schannel event logging](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260729) should get you some log information. This will log to the Event Log, however, so you'll need to find some manual way to correlate it with your IIS logs.

An [Schannel event 36880](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn786445.aspx#BKMK_36880) will be generated upon each successful negotiation. Correlating them to IIS logs is going to be a bit of a pain, to be sure, but I think this is just about the only feasible way to do it (given that Schannel doesn't really pass this information back down to IIS).

You'll get a process ID and thread ID, so you may be able to log the [APP_POOL_ID server variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx) to get a PID to use in correlation.

Comment: @But where can I find these logs to read? What is the location of this log files?

Comment: Schannel will log into the System Event Log, per the linked Microsoft article.